# Specific parts of the body are black after baking an ambient occlusion map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, ambient-occlusion

[image: viewport]

I am trying to bake an ambient occlusion map from a high poly mesh to a lower one and specific parts stay black, I've tried it with a cage , without one , and a solution from [Baking Ambient Occlusion: Almost entirely black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209358/baking-ambient-occlusion-almost-entirely-black)
but nothing changes , I have multiple maps and they've all worked when I baked except the ao map,
I tried to bake without anything other the parts I need and it didn't work(camera icon).

[blend file](https://filebin.net/ab1wvjl4ur4muak1)

Comment: We need the file.  Have you checked face orientation of high and low?

Comment: hi sorry first time asking a question ive added the file, thank you.

Comment: and the face orientation is all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file, you've got a lot of different objects.  It appears that you're set up for a bake of objects Body, Flipflops, and Shinguard to object Feet, using object Feet Cage as a cage for that bake.

But there are tons more objects in the scene, hidden, but not disabled in renders.  Like, for example, let's look at PantsCage and Shinguard at the same time:

[image]

Shinguard is completely contained with PantsCage.  At time of baking, it's unhiding PantsCage for purposes of the render-- a texture bake is considered a kind of render-- and when it goes to calculate the AO of Shinguard, it sees that it's completely occluded.  So you get black on your AO bake.

Let's move everything we want to bake over a few units in world space, so it gets out of the way of the stuff that we don't want to bake, and do a low-res quick bake to test:

[image]

And now, we see that it's baking AO okay.